# submenu is not working as it should

Tags: jquery, submenu

i'm creating a menu with submenu. i'm trying to keep the hover style of the main menu as long as the mouse in inside the submenu but as soon as i navigate from one link to another in the submenu jquery says i'm out of the submenu    http://jsfiddle.net/7gSaE/

$(document).ready(function(e) {

```
$(".menu").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).children("div").slideDown(200);
});

$(".menu").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).children("div").slideUp(200);   
});

$(".submenu").mouseenter(function(){
 $(this).parent("div.menu").children("a:first").css({"color":"#1869b4","background-color":"#ffffff"});
});

$(".submenu").mouseout(function(){
    alert("you are out of the submenu");
   $(this).parent("div.menu").children("a:first").css({"color":"#fff","background-color":"transparent"});
});

});
```

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dcWtA/1/ ?

Comment: just changing mouseout to mouseleave? thanks you can add it as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the mouseout to mouseleave

```
$(".submenu").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).parent("div.menu").children("a:first").css({
        "color": "#fff",
        "background-color": "transparent"
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dcWtA/)